# Dynamic Superfish menu problem with IE

Tags: asp.net, jquery, superfish

Almost done with my menu, but I have a problem I need to remove some parts of it depending on the user. It is ok in firefox but on IE when ever I set an li to display none it leaves a blank space instead.

Thanks.

Comment: foreach (string menuValue in menuValues)
 {
                StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
                script.Append(string.Format("var menu = $get('{0}');", menuValue));
                script.Append("if(menu != null) { menu.style.display = 'none'; }");
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), string.Format("HideMenu{0}", menuValue), script.ToString(), true);
            }

each of my li has an Id. Sorry don't know how to format code here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it, instead of using style display none I instead used jquery remove function.

Answer (score 0):

Tried

```
visibility: hidden
```

?

Also, if this is a security thing, remember that hiding the link shouldn't be the only means of security, the application should have some security of its own in case someone or google gets the link (and in my experience, google always does).